# Django FileField, ImageField on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm developing a Django app for Google App Engine and Google Cloud SQL. However, I'd like to store my FileFields in the BlobStore. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Please use Python2.7 runtime, and Files API.

Django's ImageField depends on PIL for validation, so you'll profit from using Python2.7 runtime which provides built-in PIL support. Now App Engine has an experimental files api to write data to [blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore)/[Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage) directly, so you can use this api for your purpose.

You need to add a following item in the libraries section of your app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: PIL
  version: latest
```

If you want to stick to the specific version, use '1.1.7' instead of latest.

Comment: I'm on Python 2.7, but I still don't have PIL access. Am I missing something?

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks!
However, I still need to figure out how to put it to use.

Comment: Please try it by yourself first, and if you have another question, please open a new question, with your code.